# Em qual camada de projeto com conceito DDD, devo criar uma função ou rotina para a reorganização de parcelas de um contas a receber?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, ddd

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net Core MVC no qual estou desenvolvendo um Contas a Receber. Todo o projeto usa o conceito DDD.

Preciso criar uma função para reordenar a sequência dos registros das parcelas no banco de dados, quando uma determinada parcela for excluída no banco. Devo criar, na camada infraestrutura, uma função (ex: bool reordenarParcelas(int id)) semelhante às que já existem do CRUD (ex: IEnumerable GetAll(), Parcela GetById()) ou devo criar isso na camada de Domínio (ex: CommandHandler)?

Obrigado :)

Estou seguindo o modelo do Eduardo Pires: [link](https://eduardopires.github.io/EquinoxProject/)

Comment: Cara, eu acredito que criar um command novo é o mais certo, mas depende muito, na reorganização rolam regras de negócio?

As vezes não vale a pena criar um command novo se for só pra chamar um update. (Pensando que no delete você já ta em um command)

Comment: Bem pensado @ Marccus Zavadzki! Ao fazer a exclusão, poderei fazer a reorganização de lá mesmo, pois já estarei no Command mesmo! Se eu precisar criar alguma função para executar essa rotina posteriormente, aí sim, seria viável criar um command :)

Comment: Isso aí, eu entendo que nunca tem um certo, tudo depende do contexto, como o próprio Eduardo Pires fala

Comment: Concordo plenamente! A medida que o sistema vai crescendo, várias necessidades vão surgindo e as dúvidas vão aumentando. Foi muito bom ter trocado essa ideia contigo. Obrigado :)

Comment: Comenta como resposta que eu definirei como solução para a pergunta :)

Comment: Digo o mesmo! É sempre bom discutir sobre estruturas...

Respondi aqui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depende!**

Se acontecerem regras de negócio dentro da reorganização de parcelas, é mais certo criar uma ***command*** para isso, mas, pensando que é só uma query a ser executada, como você já está em uma command no delete, as vezes não vale a pena criar outra apenas para um update...